# How can I use circular or conical gradient using CSS?

Tags: html, css

First of all, this is what I'm trying to reproduce using CSS:

[image]

I was wondering, how could I reproduce this gradient that goes from purple to pink around this circle?

Any help is really appreciated! I tried different things and nothing seems to work as intended, gradient backgrounds messed things up, border related stylish also haven't worked very well, I really don't know what to try anymore. Any ideas?

This is my code so far:

[image]

HTML & CSS:

```css
#DIV_1,
#DIV_2 {
  bottom: 0px;
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 120px;
  perspective-origin: 60px 60px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 120px / normal "Times New Roman";
  margin: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
}

#DIV_1:after,
#DIV_2:after {
  bottom: 9.60938px;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 100.797px;
  left: 9.6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 9.60938px;
  top: 9.6px;
  width: 100.797px;
  perspective-origin: 50.3906px 50.3906px;
  transform-origin: 50.3906px 50.3906px;
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 120px / normal "Times New Roman";
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
}

#SPAN_3 {
  bottom: 0px;
  color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  top: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
  column-rule-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  perspective-origin: 60px 60px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
  caret-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border: 0px none rgb(204, 204, 204);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 24px / 120px "Times New Roman";
  outline: rgb(204, 204, 204) none 0px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}

#DIV_4 {
  bottom: 0px;
  clip: rect(0px 120px 120px 60px);
  height: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 120px;
  perspective-origin: 60px 60px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 120px / normal "Times New Roman";
}

#DIV_5 {
  bottom: 0.015625px;
  clip: rect(0px 60px 120px 0px);
  height: 100.797px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.015625px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100.797px;
  perspective-origin: 59.9844px 59.9844px;
  transform: matrix(-0.587785, 0.809017, -0.809017, -0.587785, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: 59.9844px 59.9844px;
  border: 9.59375px solid rgb(77, 181, 60);
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 120px / normal "Times New Roman";
}

#DIV_6 {
  width: 120px;
  perspective-origin: 60px 0px;
  transform-origin: 60px 0px;
  border: 0px none rgb(77, 181, 60);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 120px / normal "Times New Roman";
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">
    <span id="SPAN_3">35%</span>
    <div id="DIV_4">
      <div id="DIV_5">
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a conical gradient, and there's no easy way to do that in CSS. You may be better off using an image of your desired full circle and clipping that to make the arc shape.

Comment: I could add JS to my code to do that instead of using an image, right? I'll give a look into that.

Comment: You could use a linear-gradient in a solid circle and then a smaller, solid circle drawn on top of that in the background color. Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ekkvvtx7/).

Comment: @MrLister But how do you make the 65% transparent or have no color.

Comment: I found this : http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/mLA7X/ It may not provide you with the gradient but its pretty cool eitherway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update: Chrome >68 now supports this!

#### *This was actually being implemented as `conic-gradient`.*

This is using [Chrome Canary](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) (Nov 2017) with the Experimental Features Flag set to 'enabled', but this works in the regular version as well [if you enable it.](https://www.howtogeek.com/179070/how-to-get-access-to-experimental-features-on-your-chromebook-or-just-in-chrome/)

Basic example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: conic-gradient(#F00, #0F0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Note that above example doesn't work on most browsers, but in mine, and hopefully, the future, it will display this:

[image: Conical example 1]

Now if we build our own small loading widget

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #EEE;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: conic-gradient(#f00, #0f0);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.radial-overlay {
  background-color: #EEE;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.left-half {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  clip-path: inset(0px 50px 50px 0px);
}

.right-half {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  clip-path: inset(50px 50px 0px 00px);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="radial-overlay"></div>
    <div class="right-half"></div>
    <div class="left-half"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I know most of you can't see it, but this is how it looks *with* the flags on:

[image: Conic example]

Now to edit the level, just adjust the `transform: rotate(deg)` property, you'll have to juggle arround with the left half to cover unwanted parts, but clipping path can be a great solution here.

Now of course this is all fantastic, but still very much not usable in the current browsers, Lea Verou has created a fantastic polyfill for this though, [more information about that can be found here](http://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/)

Answer (score 2):

I just made a fiddle using 2 linear gradients as background then masked them with a circular stroke and animated it with JQuery:

```js
var circle = $('#myMask circle');
var total = 2*Math.PI*circle.attr('r');
circle.attr('stroke-dasharray',total);
circle.attr('stroke-dashoffset',total);

$('button').click(function() {
  var p = $('#percentage').val() || 0;
  p = Math.max(0,Math.min(100,p))/100;
  $('#percentage-text').text(p*100+'%');
  circle.animate({'stroke-dashoffset': total-total*p}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="50%" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="myMask">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke-width="10" stroke="white" fill="transparent" transform="rotate(-90,50,50)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke-width="10" stroke="grey" fill="transparent" stroke-opacity=".2" />
  <rect x="49.5" y="0" width="52" height="100" fill="url(#grad1)" mask="url(#myMask)"/>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="49.5" height="100" fill="url(#grad2)" mask="url(#myMask)"/>
  <text id="percentage-text" x="50" y="55" text-anchor="middle">0%</text>
</svg>
<input id="percentage" type="text">
<button>Click me!</button>
```